# Custom Domains with multiple users in the Google Console

Tags: google-app-engine

So we have successfully setup custom domains with our google app engine app.

However when looking at the console they don't show up for other "owner" accounts.

Using this interface in the console here:
Compute -> App Engine -> Settings -> Custom Domains

We can see the custom domains under the account that manually setup the custom work, but the other admin/owner accounts see no custom domains.

Is this a bug in the Custom Domains interface or meant to represent something else?

Comment: hmmm... same thing happens here. Maybe you need to report this to "https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list" to have someone  from the Google team look into it?

Comment: Thanks, reported as issue.
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11786